# Number of square-free polynomials over a finite field - a combinatorial interpretation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

Cross-posted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671478/number-of-square-free-polynomials-over-a-finite-field-a-combinatorial-interpre). The question has remained unanswered for six years but I still like it!

One can show using zeta functions that the number of (monic)square-free polynomials of degree $n$ over a finite field $\Bbb F_q$ is $q^n-q^{n-1}$. For instance, this is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93560/68188).

The answer is simple enough to suggest a very nice combinatorial interpretation - the number of all monic polynomials is $q^n$ and the number of monic square-full polynomials is $q^{n-1}$.

Is there a combinatorial way to show the second statement about the number of monic squarefull polynomials is $q^{n-1}$? This is equivalent to the statement that there are q^{n-1} solutions to the discriminant being zero but the discriminant is not linear.

Update: A little calculation seems to show that the number of monic polynomials of degree $n$ that have no $k$-powers dividing them is $q^n - q^{n-k+1}$. For example, $k=2$ corresponds to the original square-free case.

One can generalize the condition that a polynomial $p(x)$ has a square factor if and only if $\gcd(p(x),p'(x)) \neq 1$ so that it is $k-$free if and only if $\gcd(p(x),p^{(1)}(x),\dots,p^{(k-1)}(x))\neq 1$.

I guess an optimal answer would explain all of these at once.

Comment: Here is a blogpost by Jordan Ellenberg with a slick proof by Mike Zieve https://quomodocumque.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/motivic-puzzle-the-moduli-space-of-squarefree-polynomials/ .

Comment: Beware of using the term 'squarefull' - it most often refers to polynomials with the property that each prime that divides them appears with multiplicity at least $2$.

Comment: The proof that uses zeta functions can be recast in completely elementary terms. Observe that each monic polynomial $f$ can be written uniquely as a monic squarefree polynomial $f_1$ times a perfect square $f_2$, and that they are unique (this follows easily from unique factorization). Hence you get the relationship $q^n=  \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} q^{i} F(n-2i) = F(n) + q F(n-2) + \ldots$ where $F(m)$ is the number of squarefrees of degree $m$. Now you can prove $F(m)=q^{m}(1-\frac{1}{q})$ if $m>1$ and $F(m)=q^m$ otherwise, by induction,

Comment: or by subtracting from the relation $q^n=F(n)+q F(n-2)+\ldots$ the relation $q(q^{n-2}) = q( F(n-2) + q F(n-4)+\ldots)$.

Comment: (note that the above derivation of $F(n)=q^n-q^{n-1}$ holds for $n\ge2$. In fact for $n\le2$ one has $F(0)=1$ and $F(1)=q$, which makes $q^n=F(n)+qF(n-2)+\dots$ a complete telescopic sum as it has to be).

Comment: Here's a generating function version of this argument.  Let $p_n$ be the number of monic polynomials of degree $n$, and let $s_n$ be the number of square-free monic polynomials of degree $n$. Then the generating function for monic polynomials that are squares is $\sum_n p_n x^{2n}$, so the unique factorization of an arbitrary monic polynomial as a square-free polynomial times a square gives
$\sum_{n}p_n x^n = \left(\sum_{n}s_n x^n\right)\left(\sum_n p_n x^{2n}\right)$. Since $p_n = q^n$,  this gives $\sum_n s_n x^n = (1-qx^2)/(1-qx)=1+qx + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (q^n - q^{n-1})x^n$.

Comment: Note that @IraGessel's comment generalises directly to $k \ge 2$.